# Inhomogeneous wave equation problem

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

Can someone tell how to solve this type of problem please?

$$\begin{cases}u_{tt}=c^2u_{xx}+e^t\sin(5t)&t>0,\,x\in(0,\pi)\\u(0,t)=0=u(\pi,t)&t>0\\u(x,0)=0&x\in(0,\pi)\\u_t(x,0)=\sin(3x)&x\in(0,\pi)\end{cases}$$

I searched on internet but all the problem  I saw had the following conditions:

$u(0,t) =$ (some function)
$u(x,0) =$ (some function)
$u_t(x,0) = 0$

But in this problem the first two conditions are equal 0 for me and the third one is not. How can I solve this please?

Comment: $0$ is still a function. Can you not use the same method given wherever you saw that example online?

Comment: I was not sure what to do when ut (x,0) = sin(3x)? because others had it equal 0

Comment: Ah ok - you wrote $u_t(x,0)=(\text{some function})$ in the question which is why I got confused. I don't have time to answer this right now, but may answer it in the morning if it hasn't been answered by then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Disclaimer:** there might be mistakes in the algebra here, I haven't thoroughly checked it. The main point of this answer is to guide you on how this can be solved.

---

You have an inhomogeneous equation with homogeneous boundary conditions - this is the form we generally want such an equation to be in. Try separation of variables $u(x,t)=\sum_{n\ge0}X_n(x)T_n(t)$. Considering the homogeneous problem to start with, $X$ satisfies the following equation. $$X''(x)+\lambda X(x)=0\\X(0)=X(\pi)=0\\\implies X_n(x)=\sin(nx),\,\,\lambda=n^2,\,\,n\in\Bbb N$$
Therefore we have $u(x,t)=\sum_{n\ge1}T_n(t)\sin(nx)$. Now note that one of the initial conditions has  a $\sin3x$ in it, and no other sine terms. So we will only keep the $n=3$ term.

Now differentiate this and compare to the inhomogeneous problem we have. $$u_{tt}-c^2u_{xx}=\left[T_3''(t)+9c^2T_3(t)\right]\sin(3x)=e^t\sin(5t)$$
Integrate with respect to $x$ from $0$ to $\pi$ to get $$\frac23\left[T_3''(t)+9c^2T_3(t)\right]=\pi e^t\sin(5t)\\T_3''(t)+9c^2T_3(t)=\frac{3\pi}2e^t\sin(5t)$$
We also have boundary conditions for $T_3$ as follows$$T_3(0)=0,T_3'(0)=1$$

This is a linear ordinary differential equation which can be solved. Once solved, combine with $\sin 3x$ and you have the solution.

---

**Edit:**

Here is the solution that you got for $T_3$:$$T_3(t)=c_1\cos(3ct)+c_2\sin(3ct)-\frac9{130}\pi e^t\sin(5t)-\frac3{65}\pi e^t\cos(5t)$$
Use the initial conditions to fix the values of $c_1$ and $c_2$. Then your final solution is $u(x,t)=y(t)\times\sin3x$.

Comment: What is about "c" in the last equation? I can simply not include in the calculation to solve the differential equation?

Comment: What do you mean? Surely if you included the $9$, then you can also include the $c$? I can see the answer you posted - to include the $c$, just change $\cos(3t)$ to $\cos(3ct)$, and the same for $\sin(3t)$. Then use the initial conditions to fix the values of $c_1$ and $c_2$. Then your final solution is $u(x,t)=y(t)\times\sin3x$.

Comment: yes I meant like "c" it's a constant right?

Comment: @gulraizsafdar Ah, I see. Yes $c$ is just a constant.

Comment: thanks again for the help :) I have another problem if you could help me with that? I don't know to write the equation like you did? Ill post the picture if you don't mind in another question that ill link it here in comment

Comment: here is the link: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2734563/initiale-value-problem-4

Comment: No problem! If you want to learn how to write maths properly on this site, have a look at this: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference. You'll often get downvotes if you attach pictures rather than typing things up, so its advisable to learn that (it isn't too hard). I may have a look at the other question later

Comment: ok thanks i'll look at the site